# Dynamically updating Ivy extra attributes

Tags: ant, ivy

I plan on using extra attributes in the ivy.xml files in an attempt to be able to get access to the revision number parts, which I need to do so that I can then use those values for the resolver pattern in the ivysettings.xml file:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="MyCompany" module="MyModule" revision="1.2.3.4" e:shortrev="1.2.3" e:buildnum="4" publication="20120207140052" />
    ...
</ivy-module>
```

I want to dynamically update the **shortrev** and **buildnum** extra attribute during the build so that when this module gets published their values will be saved with it and also so that I can use those extra attributes in the ivysettings.xml file for the resolver pattern.

```
<resolvers>
    <filesystem name="fs.resolver">
        <ivy pattern="${my.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[shortrev]/[buildnum]/ivy.xml" />
        <artifact pattern="${my.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[shortrev]/[buildnum]/[artifact].[ext]" />
    </filesystem>
</resolvers>
```

It was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10355999/275332) that I could try to use properties within the Ivy file to dynamically set their values, but I'm not clear on how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example uses the standard [buildnumber](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html) task from ANT. Unfortunately the [ivy buildnumber](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildnumber.html) task will not resolve properly for modules with extra attributes in the resolver definition :-(

## Example

```
$ tree
.
|-- build.xml
|-- ivysettings.xml
|-- ivy.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- HelloWorld.java
```

### ivy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="MyCompany" module="MyModule" e:shortrev="${publish.target.revision}" e:buildnum="${publish.buildnumber}"/>

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="compile->default">
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="runtime" description="Shared library needed at runtime" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="runtime"/>
    </configurations>

    <publications>
        <artifact name="MyModule" type="jar" e:shortrev="${publish.target.revision}" e:buildnum="${publish.buildnumber}"/>
    </publications>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6"/>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.2" conf="test->default"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Notes:

- The extra attributes are associated with **both** the info and artifact definitions.

### build.xml

```
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" name="publish-example" default="build">

    <!--
    ==========
    Properties
    ==========
    -->
    <property name="src.dir"     location="src/main"/>
    <property name="build.dir"   location="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" location="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="reports.dir" location="${build.dir}/reports"/>

    <property name="publish.target.revision" value="1.2.3"/>
    <property name="publish.status"   value="release"/>
    <property name="publish.resolver" value="custom.repository"/>

    <!--
    =======
    Targets
    =======
    -->
    <target name='init' description='Resolve project dependencies and set classpaths'>
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:report todir='${reports.dir}' graph='false' xml='false'/>

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path"  conf="compile"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="runtime.path"  conf="runtime"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"     conf="test"/>

        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" classpathref="compile.path"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="compile">
        <ivy:info/>
        <jar destfile="${build.dir}/${ivy.module}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="publish-revision" description="Determine the new published revision">
        <buildnumber/>

        <property name="publish.revision" value="${publish.target.revision}.${build.number}"/>
        <property name="publish.buildnumber" value="${build.number}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="publish" depends="build,publish-revision" description="Publish artifacts into repository">
        <ivy:deliver deliverpattern="${build.dir}/ivy.xml" pubrevision="${publish.revision}" status="${publish.status}"/>

        <ivy:publish resolver="${publish.resolver}" pubrevision="${publish.revision}" overwrite="true">
            <artifacts pattern="${build.dir}/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </ivy:publish>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="--> clean project files">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="--> clean ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache />
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- The ivy [deliver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/deliver.html) task ensures that the published ivy file is properly populated.

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
        <filesystem name="custom.repository">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[shortrev]/[buildnum]/ivy.xml" />
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[shortrev]/[buildnum]/[artifact].[ext]" />
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Notes:

- I always setup Maven Central as my default resolver, in order to retrieve 3rd party dependencies like commons-lang and junit.
- The **custom.repository** resolver is configured within the build file as the property "publish.resolver"

Comment: I think this may work pretty well for us.  Are you currently using something like this in your build system?

Comment: I use Nexus as my repository manager. This means my repository format is Maven, rather than custom layout like yours. Beauty of ivy is that it's tremendeously flexible.